# Infinite ladder of capacitors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

Why isn't the equivalent capacitance C only? The charge through each capacitor can be 1/2 of the previous capacitor and the sum of the voltage drops will be equal to total voltage. This gives the equivalent capacitance to be equal to the value of the identical capacitors.

[image]

Comment: What does this "infinite ladder of capacitors" look like? Is it an infinite chain of capacitors in series, or in parallel, or in some other configuration?

Comment: In any case, the sum of the voltage drops _along any one path from +  to -_ will be equal to the total voltage, but there are an infinite number of distinct paths here, with each capacitor being part of an infinite number of paths.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's look in steps:

1. The first two left capacitors, give:
   $$\text{C}_1=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{C}}+\frac{1}{\text{C}}}=\frac{\text{C}}{2}\tag1$$
2. The next two added, gives:
   $$\text{C}_2=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{C}}+\frac{1}{\text{C}_1+\text{C}}}=\frac{3}{5}\cdot\text{C}\tag2$$

So, in general we have:

$$\text{C}_\text{n}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{C}}+\frac{1}{\text{C}_{\text{n}-1}+\text{C}}}\tag3$$

So, when $\text{n}\to\infty$ we need to solve:

$$\text{C}_\text{equiv}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{C}}+\frac{1}{\text{C}_\text{equiv}+\text{C}}}\space\Longrightarrow\space\text{C}_\text{equiv}=\frac{\text{C}}{2}\cdot\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)\approx0.618033\cdot\text{C}\tag4$$

Comment: If you cut the wires to the right of the first two capacitors then the capacitance of the rest is $C_{equiv}$, so you can write your last equation directly.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please? I can't understand how the capacitors are actually getting added. In the first step you add the two capacitors C in series thus giving a new equivalent capacitance of C/2 but where the new capacitor is being placed and how it is in series in the first place? I don't understand the second step in which the denominator of the second term in the denominator is C1 + C, are you adding in parallel here somehow? Explaining the steps with the help of a diagram will be helpful.